# Can't login to root account

Tags: permissions, root, su

I restricted the use of su by creating an admin group

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin "admin user"
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update -add root admin 4750 /bin/su
```

Later I regretted this so I removed the following line

```
root admin 4750 /bin/su
```

from /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride and I removed the admin group.

My /bin/su permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 44664 Jan 25  2018 /bin/su
```

When I try to login to root account with the new root account password I get

```
su: Authentication failure
```

I've no intentions of using the root account but I find this annoying. How do I solve this?

Comment: You appear to have removed the setuid bit from /bin/su - see similar issue here: [SU Authentication failure - Help!!](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1084068)

Comment: Thanks man/woman!!! sudo chmod 4755 /bin/su did it. Now I can finally go to sleep.